# Bootstrap grid not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask, raspberry-pi3

I've been working on a simple webpage to display three images in the top row and three in the bottom. I haven't even been able to get this test page working properly.

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Jessie, using flask 0.10.1.

Here is the view:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',
               title='testpage')`
```

and the HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-3-sm-3-md-3-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3-sm-3-md-3-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3-sm-3-md-3-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3-sm-3-md-3-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12-sm-12-md-12-lg-12">
        <h1>1 Col here
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I initially tried sourcing the bootstrap files locally as the web server will be running on an intranet, but when that didn't work I commented it out and added the CDN links.

The page loads the text properly, but all in one central column. there doesn't seem to be any 'grid' to speak of. Does anyone have any suggestions what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in define class. it should like this:
`col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  

      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <h1>3 Cols here
        </h1>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <h1>1 Col here
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I managed to deduce it was in that div but didn't realise the syntax was incorrect.